# Making a drop down from multiple options in a db

Tags: php, sql

I want to be able to generate a drop down list from items entered into a row in a table in SQL. the row is called 'locations'. so lets say, i have the following records:

- NAME | LOCATION
- img_01 | sydney
- img_02 | perth
- img_03 | perth
- img_04 | perth
- img_05 | melbourne
- img_06 | melbourne

What would be the best way to query the database to list the different locations in the db (only once for each location).

ie, would return
sydney, perth, melbourne.

Thanks.

Comment: This has got to be the 12867th time this gets asked here.

Comment: do you want to explain or link  me then?

Comment: Are each of the items in your list above in one field? Oh vey...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just get a list of locations use

```
select distinct location from yourTableName
```

You could then build your select by looping through those results.

Or you could alternatively do something like:

```
select distinct CONCAT("<option>",location,"</option>") from yourTableName
```

which would remove the need for you to loop through the results to build the options in html, you could just take that result and drop it between your select tags.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, try this :

```
echo "<select>\n";

foreach ($locations as $l) echo "<option>$l</option>\n";

echo "</select>"
```

Comment: this creates an option for every location. i only want it to create one option for multiple rows with the same category

Comment: You want the SQL query ? If yes : "SELECT DISTINCT LOCATION FROM 'locations'" Not sure to understand well.